# IIS showing forbidden when using HTTPS but works fine with HTTP

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have deployed my web app to IIS and it works fine with http but
whenever I try to access it using https it immediately shows me a
forbidden error.
I gave access to IIS_IUSRS, IUSRS, Network Service but still nothing works.

**EDIT**

FULL ERROR PAGE

[image: 403 - Forbidden]

**EDIT**

HOW I GOT THE SSL CERTIFICATE FILES

The client had previously imported the certificate to IIS incorrectly. So I asked them for the .pfx file and then imported it myself using mmc. And finally added the binding to my web app where I selected https and the imported certificate. That's all I did and it just doesn't work.

Comment: Does [Access denied error when running site with SSL](https://serverfault.com/questions/255571/access-denied-error-when-running-site-with-ssl) help?

Comment: No it doesn't. I don't have the "Require SSL" option checked.

Comment: Edit your question to include the full error page please. Never ask others to guess.

Comment: If you look in the IIS log files, there will be a sub-code with the status code. You can decode it with [The HTTP status code in IIS 7.0 and later versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/http-status-code) to get more information.

Comment: I am looking at the log files for my web app but there is no entry for a request at port 443. However, there is one request that has the 403 forbidden status but the thing is that it is not the url that I am testing on. This one: #Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2021-02-15 14:04:33 IP.ADDRESS.COM GET / - 80 - IP.ADDRESS.COM Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.3;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/88.0.4324.150+Safari/537.36 - 403 4 5 472

Comment: The way the error message is coming it doesn't look like it's from IIS. There is no formatting at all. I checked the IIS error pages and they look completely different. Is there a firewall or something that could cause this? I read somewhere about ISA Server but couldn't find it in my server.

Comment: Which authentication did you use, anonymous or client certificate mapping? which identity did you configured for application pool identity? Is there any other substatus code for 403 error? Have you disabled the ssl offloading? Please try to grant permission for user group and configure application pool identity to network service.

Comment: @imran.razak Are there any rewrite rules in web.config which could be rewriting the URL?